# fatal error during ubuntu 20.04 installation

Tags: usb, 20.04

I made usb bootable with universal usb installer, booted into ubuntu. At ubuntu graphical interface I chose install option. That's where I recived a message fatal error. But failed to save an image in progress. Now have this interface [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsnWl.jpg) with the option to try to reinstall and it does not leave that part. Before I had Windows 10 installed. Somebody help me, please!

Answer (score 0):

this is the page of the problem that was generated after installation. It is something related to the boot. I'm new to linux https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WKkB3zYtRX/

Comment: This should have been added as an edit to the question, and the pastebin no longer exists.